# Open New Windows from Background Thread on ViewModel

Tags: wpf, multithreading, mvvm

So I have a WPF application (MVVM) with a Splash Screen.  On the splash screen startup I have a background thread on the ViewModel that does some start up related activities.  In certain instances I want to open a couple of additional windows (user input needed etc...).  I was getting a number of issues/errors/exceptions while trying to do this (mostly around that new window - also MVVM - trying to populate its UI items, such as combo boxes).  So I've pulled back the issue to a simpler form - the "tempWindow" doesn't have anything so it doesn't throw UI population errors, but basically it does just open them and once the background thread is done, closes them all.  If someone could point me in the right direction on what I am doing incorrectly here it would be appreciated.

The constructor for the ViewModel kicks off a background thread

```
public SplashScreenViewModel()
{            
   this.LoadingStatusText = "Starting Startup Processing ... ";
   this.VersionNumber = "version " + System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();

   var threadBackgroundStartUpProcesses = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.BackgroundStartUpProcesses));
   threadBackgroundStartUpProcesses.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
   threadBackgroundStartUpProcesses.IsBackground = true;
   threadBackgroundStartUpProcesses.Start();
}
```

The background thread, should just open three windows (which it does) but those windows should stay open (they disappear once the thread completes).

```
private void BackgroundStartUpProcesses()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        var objTempWindow = new tempWindow();
        objTempWindow.Show();
    }
}
```

// EDIT: updated with responses, now get an error when the TempWindow has a comboBox that is being populated from the TempWindowViewModel.

```
private void BackgroundStartUpProcesses()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        var objTempWindow = new tempWindow();
        objTempWindow.Show();
    }

    System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
}
```

When it goes to open the TempWindow the exception: "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it." is thrown and appears to be when a ComboBox on that Window is trying to be populated.

Comment: i ended up creating a list of windows to be created, then at the end of the startup raising an event with that list of windows and passing that back to the WPF SplashScreenView via that event, then on the view handling that event, looping through the list of views and opening the windows from there ... not sure if this is best, but it works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that windows need an owner and when the owner dies, so does the window. Opening the windows on the main thread makes them stick around. Something like this...

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var threadBackgroundStartUpProcesses = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(this.BackgroundStartUpProcesses));
        threadBackgroundStartUpProcesses.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        threadBackgroundStartUpProcesses.IsBackground = true;
        threadBackgroundStartUpProcesses.Start(System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher);
    }

    private void BackgroundStartUpProcesses(object d)
    {
        System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher dispatcher = (System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher) d;
         for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
         {
             dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
             {
                 var objTempWindow = new tempWindow();
                 objTempWindow.Show();

             }));

         }

    }
}
```

**edit**

I've just done some digging on WPF threading and it looks like you can open windows on multiple threads, but you need to start the new dispatcher. See near the end of this page:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741870.aspx

In your `BackgroundStartupProcesses`, under `objTempWindow.Show()` add this line

```
System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
```

Comment: iteresting, that seems to keep the last window around (the Dispatcher.Run() suggestion) but not the other two ...

Comment: Sorry, my bad. You need to put it outside the loop, at the bottom.

Comment: thanks ... this definitely works for this reduced case, hopefully when i add back in the mvvm on the "tempWindow" it will keep working ... thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting your `MainWindow` before closing the splash screen? WPF sets the first opened window of an application as the `MainWindow` and unless you've changed the `ShutdownMode` of your `App.xaml` then once you close the splash screen the application shuts down.

Comment: i've don't set MainWindow, i don't set it to anything on the App.xaml and then on the Application_Startup I do the var objSplashScreenView = new UI.SplashScreen.SplashScreenView(); objSplashScreenView.ShowCentered();

Comment: So your splash screen becomes the MainWindow, when you close your splash screen it closes the whole application. Fiddle around with the ShutdownMode in App.xaml or try setting the MainWindow.